# Changing color of radio button moment after

Tags: android, time, colors, radio-button

Ok so i have radiobuttons that repressent correct and incorrect answer. What would like is to turn color of that button to some color for a moment and then turn it right back to its default color that i have already defined but i do not know how to implement this default color(R.drawable.radiodefault) to appear and change back color of the radiobutton moment after R.drawable.tocan/R.drawable.netocan is shown

```
if(currentQ.getANSWER().equals(answer.getText()))
        {
            answer.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.radiotocan);



        }
        else if(currentQ.getANSWER()!=answer.getText()){


                answer.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.radionetocan);



        }`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem might be in your else if condition. You are comparing strings with !=

```
if(currentQ.getANSWER().equals(answer.getText())){
   answer.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.radiotocan);
} else if(!currentQ.getANSWER().equals(answer.getText())){
   answer.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.radionetocan);
}
```

If there are no additional conditions then it would be better to use else instead of else if.

As for changing it back to default you could use handler.

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable(){
   @Override
   public void run(){
      //change it back
      answer.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.radiodefault);
   }
}, delayInMillis);
```